# Azure App Service Environment v3 and Logic App Standard - cannot be associated

Tags: azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-logic-app-standard

I have an ASEv3 just created in West Europe.
I want to create an App Service Plan for Logic App Standard so I'm trying first to associate my App Service Plan with the ASEv3. Unfortunately, when I go to the "choose the size" panel, my ASEV3 is not listed in the "Spec piker". Instead, it asks me to create a new plan which sounds strange.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the ASEV3 is in fact in the list of "regions", this is why I was not able to associate it with my App Service Plan.